# Show that $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_{23})$ has subgroup of index $2$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-isomorphism, group-homomorphism

> Show that $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_{23})$ has subgroup of index $2$

We know that $|GL_n(\mathbb{F}_{23})|=(23^n-1)(23^n-23) \dots (23^n-23^{n-1})$

and therefore is even.

I thought about Cauchy theorem but I don't know that  $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_{23})$ is abelian... Any ideas?

**EDIT**

Ok so I get it that I should is the first isomorphism theorem, and get that the kernel is of index $2$, but I don't understand how to build that isomorphism...

Comment: Is there anyone here who can give an elaborated solution? Please

Comment: Anyone? It's very important...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

$\det: GL_n(\Bbb F_{23})\to\Bbb F_{23}^*$ is a surjective homomorphism. Now, $\Bbb F_{23}^*\cong \Bbb Z/22\Bbb Z$, thus it surjects onto $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ via the quotient map $\pi:\Bbb Z/22\Bbb Z\to\frac{\Bbb Z/22\Bbb Z}{2\Bbb Z/22\Bbb Z}$. So, $\ker(\pi\circ\det)$ has index $2$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why $\mathbb{Z}_{22}$ surjective onto $\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: I understand that you used here the first isomorphism theorem, but can you please explain it a bit more?